# JavaScript: I need to iterate over each character in `strArray` and see if it exists in `charArray`

Tags: javascript

I am given a string and an array of single character strings as an argument. I need to return the shortest substring that can be found in the given string that contains every character in the array.

I am assuming that all characters are lower case and that the substring will be at least two characters long.

This is how I have it set up:

```
const solve = (strArg, charArray) => {
  let result = '';
  const strArray = strArg.split('');
  return;
}

solve("environmental earth science", ["n","e","i","m"]);
```

I want to loop over the `strArg` and say does this letter exist in the `charArray`, but I want to use an ES6 array helper method and I have looked at `filter()`, but if I look at how T.J Crowder [defines the use of `filter()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript), that is more for creating a new array.

So then I have also looked at the `for..of` loop, but I am unclear as to whether I am applying it wrong or the `for..of` is not the best for the job. I need to iterate over each character in `strArray` and see if it exists in `charArray`.

Comment: `"environmental earth science".split("").filter( x=>!"neim".contains(x))`

Comment: `"environmental earth science".replace(RegExp("[neim]", "g"), "")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A brute-force solution would be to start at each index of the input string, then increment indicies until all required characters have been found. Do this starting at index 0, then at index 1, etc.

```js
const solve = (str, charArray) => {
  let bestStr = str;
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    const chars = new Set(charArray);
    for (let j = i; j < str.length; j++) {
      chars.delete(str[j]);
      const thisLen = j - i + 1;
      if (chars.size === 0 && bestStr.length > thisLen) {
        bestStr = str.slice(i, j + 1);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return bestStr;
}

console.log(solve("environmental earth science", ["n","e","i","m"]));
```

I don't think `filter` is very useful here, because constructing an intermediate array doesn't lead to accomplishing anything useful as far as I can see. `for..of`, while it *looks* cleaner, doesn't keep track of indicies as well as a plain `for` loop.

Comment: I had heard about this brute force solution but I thought maybe that was not the ideal solution. Thank you.

Comment: It's a solution to the problem in your question, which is probably a lot better than not knowing where to start. If `O(n ^ 2)` solutions are not permitted, probably best to edit your question to specify such

Comment: shouldn't the output be `nme` instead of `ironme` in this case?

Comment: @shrys That doesn't contain every letter of the `charArray` argument, so it wouldn't be a solution, right? *return the shortest substring that can be found in the given string that contains every character in the array.*

Comment: @CertainPerformance, thanks again. I was not criticizing your answer, its a new problem for me and when I saw "brute force" on some websites, it sounded hacky, but what did I know?

Comment: @CertainPerformance, And thanks for exposing me to the `Set` object.